# Using sed I want to delete "... 12 more" / "... 14 more" string from java stack trace

Tags: sed

I have a use case were I want to remove "... 12 more" / "... 14 more" string from java stack trace

For an example :

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2708)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:86)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:76)
    ... 14 more
```

I tried below command but it deletes the entire content.

```
# sed -i '/^\s*at/d ; /^\s*.../d file.txt
```

Any help please !!

Comment: It works when I use "/^\s*... .* more/d" but I just want to use ". . ."  in sed expression.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/^\s\+\(at\|\.\.\.\)\s/d'
```

Select lines which begin `^` with one or more spaces `\s\+` followed by `\(` either `at` or `\|` three periods `\.\.\.` `\)` and a space `\s`; delete `d` those lines.

Or, with extended RE syntax:

```
sed -Ee '/^\s+(at|\.\.\.) /d'
```

(In a regular expression `.` means any character; a period is `\.`.)